# Why do my Not An Answer flags keep getting declined or disputed?

Tags: support, flagging

Every now and again I flag something as not trying to answer the question (maybe extra tangential information), but then the flag is disputed or declined.

Am I too trigger-happy with my flagging or something?

Comment: I’ve pretty much given up flagging NAAs here, because the flags are nearly always declined (and yet, in many cases, the post ends up removed through other means, or converted to a comment on appeal). Even [when the moderators seem to agree](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17619/79) they end up disinclined to act upon the flags in some cases :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Blame the review queues for the disputed flags.

For the declined ones – or, at least, those I've looked at – you've flagged answers that *do* answer the question, like [this one](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/3244/278):

> **Question**: Which tools were used to create the C language?
> **Answer**: TMG was […] used […] to write […] B […].

This answers the question (imo), because B was made into C incrementally; early C compilers were “B++” compilers.

A NAA would be something like:

> **Question**: Which tools were used to create the C language?
> **Answer**: C++ evolved from a C preprocessor called Cpre, which implemented “C with Classes”.

You see that this doesn't answer the question. Here's something else that is not NAA:

> **Question**: Which tools were used to create the C language?
> **Answer**: The first C compiler was written in Python.

It answers the question! It's also wrong; downvote, and perhaps flag as Very Low Quality (something as egregiously wrong as this is probably a troll). But NAA is not an appropriate flag.

Comment: Could you explain [this one](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18120/79) then? I’m clearly not the only Retro.SE user to think that it’s absolutely not an answer — or rather, that it’s an answer to a different question, and therefore posted in the wrong place, and thus NAA.

Comment: @StephenKitt I think that one is a valid attempt to answer the question.  Clearly there are problems with it but I'm happy to give the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Chenmunka there’s *nothing* there about non-monolithic CPUs. It’s a valid attempt to answer [the linked question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11801/79), not the question it’s posted under.

Comment: Mods can move answers from one question to another, can’t they?

Comment: @StephenKitt Only when there's only one answer on the question, and even then it's a hack.

Comment: In that case I'd as well would delete it, as it does not really answer anything useful to the original question - in fact, its even in itself a failure, as the his own addition is simply wrong (the 32 bit was needed to handle subroutine mode switches to support linking of older 24 bit code), so all that's left is a quote only answer.